# How to force the update of radio buttons in Webix datatable

Tags: javascript, database, datatable, radio-button, webix

Is there a way to force the update for each change of the radio buttons in Webix datatable?

I have a datatable like

```
var list = [{ 
  id:1, user:"", mail:"", rad:''
}, { 
  id:2, user:"", mail:"", rad:''
}, { 
  id:3, user:"", mail:"", rad:''
}, { 
  id:4, user:"", mail:"", rad:''
}, { 
  id:5, user:"", mail:"", rad:''
}]; 


webix.ui({  
  view:"datatable",
  data:list,
  columns:[{ 
    id:"ra1", header:"", template:"{common.radio()}", width:50
  }, { 
    id:"user",  sort:"string", header:"Name", adjust:true
  }, {
    id:"mail",  editor:"text",      header:"E-mail" , adjust:true
  }]
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9covejnt/2/

But I don't have a clue how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use onCheck event to add some reaction for radio input clicking

Something like next

```
webix.ui({  
  view:"datatable",
  on:{
    onCheck:function(id){
      //do something 
      //next line triggers default data saving logic
      webix.dp(this).save(id);
    }
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9covejnt/3/